# Knowing when KML file has loaded and features added (OpenLayers3)?

Tags: openlayers-3

I see that [ol.source.KML](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/apidoc/ol.source.KML.html) (untick "Stable only") fires the events `addfeature`, 
`change` and `removefeature`. However, I just need to know when the KML was retrieved over the network and all its features added. Is there an event like "loaded" or similar in OpenLayers 3?

I need to execute some code when the KML has been added. Waiting for `document.ready` is not enough as the KML file is loaded (over network) afterwards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Listen to `change` event, check if the source [state](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/apidoc/ol.source.html#State) is `ready`, then do what you want, not forgetting to deregister your listener.

`var key = source.on('change', function() {
  if (source.getState() == 'ready') {
    source.unByKey(key);
    // do something with the source
  }
});`